# Display full column name instead of shortened

Tags: sql, oracle, sqlplus

If I write:

```
Select DUMMY from DUAL;
```

it's displayed as follows:

```
D
-
X
```

Why is the column name 'D' here ? Why not the full "DUMMY"? How can I get the result to display as follows?

```
Dummy
-----
  X
```

The above problem is now solved. Now, what would be done if we want back to its default ?

```
    col dummy format a1;
    insert into tab values('a');
    insert into tab values('ank');
    select * from tab;
```

The Output is :

```
    D
    -
    a
    a
    n
    k
```

This 'Dummy' column is NOT from Dual table. Its my own created table 'tab'.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

SQL*Plus will format the column width to the size of the datatype. in the case of DUAL, DUMMY is a varchar2(1). you can control this with

```
col DUMMY format a5
```

ie:

```
SQL> select * from dual;

D
-
X

SQL> col DUMMY format a5
SQL> select * from dual;

DUMMY
-----
X
```

Comment: For reference, if you are aliasing your column names, then you need to set the format of the aliased name, not the underlying column name.  Had me confused for a while, as I assumed that it wouldn't know of the aliases until the query ran, but apparently it maintains a lookup somewhere of formats that have been defined, and only if there isn't a defined format for that column alias (or name if no alias defined) does it revert to the length of the underlying data.

Answer (score 1):

"Cheating"

```
Select rpad('x', 5, ' ') DUMMY from DUAL
/

SQL>

DUMMY
-----
x
```

Comment: @Ben, You probably meant datatype. The dummy is varchar2 in dual. When you select * from dual you select a char...

Comment: @Ben, in both cases the data returned is char. Just to clarify as I'm still not sure I understand your correctly. It does not really matter as long as we were able to help the person who asks... My version is a shortcut and "cheating" - no need to use SQL+ commands as in first answer...

Comment: No @art; the _datatypes_ are the same the _data_ is not. In the first case the data returned is a `varchar2(1)`, `X` only. In your case it's a `varchar2(5)`, `X    ` right padded with 4 spaces.

Comment: -1 is what you get for sharing knowledge. I guess some "expert" was not ready for "cheating"...